# Cast varbinary(8)/timestamp column to varchar(max) get empty string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The fallowing code

```
declare @b varbinary(8) = 1
select cast(@b as varchar(max)), @b
```

returns

```
Casted  Original
        0x00000001
```

How to cast the timestamp/varbinary value to varchar? Expected "0x00000001".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for your scenario

```
select convert(varchar, @b, 1), @b   // <---- 0x00000001
```

This could help you: [Convert binary value to string value](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_larsson/archive/2010/01/27/convert-binary-value-to-string-value.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I had so much trouble converting to/from binary(8) to varchar see the function below does the convertion.

```
declare @binary binary(8)
declare @radhe varchar(100)   -- this is just a variable to store the returning value at the end 

select @binary = 0x000000000000037A

;with ctea as
(
select maxlen = MAX(len(@binary)) 
) ,
cte as
(
select i = 1
union all
select i = i + 1 from cte,ctea where i < maxlen
) ,
cte2 as
(
select i, j=convert(int,SUBSTRING(@binary,i,1)) from cte
),
cte3 as
(
select  i, j=j/16, k=j%16 from cte2
),
ctehex as
(
select  i
   ,j
   ,k
   ,h1=case when j<10 then convert(varchar(1),j) 
            else CHAR(55+j) 
       end
  ,h2=case when k<10 then convert(varchar(1),k) 
           else CHAR(55+k) 
      end
from cte3
)

select  @radhe = '0x'+(select h1+h2 from ctehex  for xml path (''))

select @radhe as [the varchar value], @binary as [the binary(8) value]
```

-- hope this helps M